# representing a shift/timetable using a database

Tags: mysql, database, timetable

I'm trying to figure out the best way to represent an employee shift table by using a database.
I have:

1. A table of employees
2. A table of shift types (ie. morning shift, afternoon shift)
3. A table with the shift date, shift_type id and employee id

The problem is that a shift can include more than one employee (I would not like to limit the amount of employees per shift), so I guess my 3rd table's structure isn't fit for this.

What would be your recommendation?

Comment: why wouldn't it be? two records `(2015-12-01,1, 10),(2015-12-01,1,20)` would indicate that on dec 1st, 2 employees (#10 and #20) worked the #1 shift.

Comment: Thanks, it just occurred to me last night that this is probably the best  solution.